# What would cause a buck-boost regulator to buzz loudly and generate high voltage ripple during certain input voltages?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck, boost

I've got a buck-boost power supply design based on the LM5118 by TI. A schematic of the device is shown below:

[image: SMPS Schematic]

([Link](http://webench.ti.com/appinfo/webench/scripts/SDP.cgi?ID=9F380CD6D78061CF) to TI Workbench)

**EDIT** Many of the comments mention the layout, hence I've included a screenshot of the top and bottom side of the board here. I've also included the schematic so that the component references match up.

Top side:
[image: Top side PCB]

Bottom side:
[image: Bottom side PCB]

Schematic:
[image: Schematic 01]

[image: Schematic 02]

**NOTE:** The schematic does use slightly different parts than what the TI Workbench suggests. These were calculated by following the process in the datasheet and using the Excel-based calculator TI mention in the datasheet. When this original setup didn't work, the components were replaced to match the ones suggested by the Workbench, but that still hasn't solved the issue.

What I've found is that with a load of 0.5A, between 10-16V input, the device emits a loud whining noise, which appears to be coming from the inductor. At the same time, the output voltage has a 1.5V pk-pk ripple at about 5kHz. Once the voltage is raised above approximately 16V, the noise stops and the power supply appears to be functioning correctly, with a clean 13.5V output.

I've scoped the gate signals for the transistors and noticed that when the power supply is generating that noise, the signals to the gate appear to be discontinuous. The controller will drive the gate at the switching frequency (approx 300kHz) for a period of time then there will be a gap, where the gate is just turned off for a period of time, then the switching resumes. I haven't measured the frequency of this overall behaviour - at a guess, I bet it's not going be too far off the 5kHz.

I had another power supply designed using the same chip that was initially designed for 28V output and worked perfectly fine. The feedback resistors were then modified to provide a 13.5V output and it continued to work fine across the entire voltage range. The only difference between that design and this one were the transistors ([SQM120N10-3M8-GE3](http://www.vishay.com/docs/63404/sqm120n10-3m8.pdf)) and the diodes ([MBRS3201T3G](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MBRS3201T3-D.PDF)).

Any thoughts on what I could look for to help troubleshoot this?

Comment: Scope the hot side of the inductor. You may be catching gaussian reflections in the inductor at a given voltage

Comment: Check this similiar question here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77645/can-a-synchronous-regulator-chirp-in-burst-mode the Noise could be due to 'burst mode' operation of the regulator, but this would happen only at lighter loads, dig deeper into the lm5118 data sheet for more info on its various operating modes.

Comment: @user7994 Thanks. However, it seems that burst mode is considered "normal operation" for some regulators. In my case, the output voltage ripple is huge during this strange mode, which indicates to me that something's wrong.

Comment: try playing around with the loop compensation, the type 2 RC network connected to the COMP pin. Some simple math should help you calculate the right values for the RC compensation network. Section 10.2.2.17 in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5118.pdf) for the LM5118 has more info, the RC feedback components are marked in the [schematic] (http://imgur.com/XiNsRwL)

Comment: It could be a gain/phase margin issue as suggested above, but it could also be a noise issue due to PCB layout.  I have seen layout problems that only show up during certain ranges as described.  When the converter is stable you could run a gain/phase plot if you have the equipment to see your gain and phase margin. If not, you could get an idea by looking at load transient response.

Comment: I bet it's circuit layout or too light a load....

Comment: So, stable in Buck mode and unstable in Buck-Boost. Right half plane zero perhaps? Noise interference while driving the Boost FET? And why such a honking FET 125nC of gate charge at 300kHz must be close to 300mW gate drive power. Insufficient gate dampening maybe.

Comment: Your issue is occurring when transitioning from boost to buck mode, and this strongly suggests loop compensation (including layout) or perhaps output to input coupling via PCB tracks. I will note that ringing occurs at high duty cycles (at least for buck mode), and there is a mode dependency on duty cycle (data sheet figure 10) and that rather reinforces my suspicion.

Comment: On the transition region from buck to buck-boost - figure 16 shows the transition starting at about 2.5V above V(out), which would fit with your observed 16V clean operation.

Comment: @PeterSmith Thanks for your comments. Since the layout seems to have been called into question several times, I've updated the question to include the PCB layout, in case that brings up any obvious problems.

Comment: It might be worth you looking at TI's reference PCB design for this part and comparing how they have done it: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snva334b/snva334b.pdf

Comment: Gentlemen, the layout is far from being perfect, but it's not the reason for acoustic noise.

Comment: Having seen apparently benign layouts cause the weirdest problems in SMPS circuits - lets just say I am always suspicious of this set of hidden schematic elements. There are two things interesting in the layout: 1. There appears to be a solid ground plane - if this is solid between pin 1 and pin 20, you could easily have output switch node noise coupling right back into the input which can easily destabilise the circuit. 2. There is a track underneath L1, where you can expect severe noise (shielded inductors aren't *that* shielded). Look at the Vin pin on a scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like everyone who said it was the loop compensation was right! But I've led everyone on a bit of a wild goose chase - the problem was a mistake on the schematic that must have occurred when it was being modified from one iteration to the next: R6 is meant to connect to COMP, but is connected to FB! So, it was indeed the loop compensation not working properly!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking here: http://www.smpstech.com/problems.htm, the guy seems quite knowledgeable and the site is full of interesting SMPS-related reading.

Comment: That domain is now being squatted by advertisers

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i am too lazy to read all comments.

Still, i have some thoughts for the subject. DC/DC often have notable ripple of frequency like 0.1 or 0.01 of the switching frequency. That means, that the control circuit does not work very well. First thing you could try is playing with all those caps of compensation network. Also adding a small cap in parallel with top feedback resistor may be really helpful.

Now, in your layout i can't see the MOSFETs. Either i just miss them on my cell phone screen, or they are far from the driver. In that case you are going to experience issues with EMI caused by high gate and drain currents. Be careful with that too.

Comment: Thanks. The transistors are there: look to the left and right of L1

Comment: So they are q1,q3, not m1,m2?

Comment: Yes, that's them.

Comment: Just look at all the way gate current must pass to q1. It's probably like 2A with rise time of maybe 20nsec. Pretty awful.

Comment: No no, it's Q2 and Q3.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i mean q2. :) look at that trace... Anyway, it's not what causes ripple on the output. When can you try the small capacitor on feedback? I bet it will work. Try like 47pF, maybe 1000pF.

Comment: By the way, this capacitor is "feed forward" feature, which in layman's terms means that you don't want to wait for your control circuit to do the job, instead you feed the change itself to the feedback, so the whole thing works a little faster.

Comment: Q3 gate trace looks not much better. If you will need to path EMI lab, make new board. Last time i risked to do something like that (i was younger and braver than now), the board interfered with itself.

Comment: What are the current paths for the gate signals for Q2-3? Also, what other issues do you see with the layout?

Comment: The current path is all the way from DC/DC controller to the MOSFET gate. The key idea of switching power supply is that the switch is only ON or OFF, no state in the middle. So to come as close to that as possible, the time it takes to turn on or off the MOSFET is minimized by high charge current. Now, look where it flows. It starts on DC/DC internal gate driver, goes to the MOSFET gate, to MOSFET source, to the ground, to decoupling capacitor near the DC/DC. Then the mesh is closed. If this mesh is big and wide, it's just an antenna, transmitting pretty high energy to unknown direction.

Comment: So when you make a DC/DC placement, you should look on all current paths you have. To MOSFETs, to inductor, to catch diode, and make sure about two things. 1: all paths are as short as possible. 2: if due to the switching there is change in loop area, the change is minimal, so the magnetic flux remains constant.

Comment: Specifically in your layout i would take q2 lower, where smaller capacitors are, diodes would be9 on bottom side right under q2, U1 then would be rotated 90 degrees and placed in parallel with the inductor, q3 would be right near on under output capacitors.