# Switching power supply layout review

Tags: pcb-design, switch-mode-power-supply, layout, emc

In a [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/191006/what-would-cause-a-buck-boost-regulator-to-buzz-loudly-and-generate-high-voltage.) where a SMPS based on an [LM5118](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5118.pdf) was presented, some aspects of the layout were pointed out as being problematic. I've taken another look at the layout of that section of the board and in light of the advice given, the [IC datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5118.pdf) and [reference design](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snva334b/snva334b.pdf), I've made some modifications to the layout with the aim of resolving any layout issues.

Here's the top side:

[image: Top Layer]

Bottom side (as viewed from top):

[image: Bottom side]

Schematic page 1:

[image: Schematic 1]

Schematic page 2:

[image: Schematic 2]

Things I've tried to keep in mind:

- I've tried to keep the bottom layer continuous underneath the high current loops so that the return currents can travel along the bottom layer, directly beneath the top layer, thus minimising the loop area.
- Separate ground area for the analogue section of the SMPS, connecting directly to the AGND pin.
- Solid ground plane between PGND pins, input and output caps.
- Gate signal for Q2 rerouted to move it away from the inductor and to try and improve its loop area.

I appreciate that other parts of the circuit (not shown) can have an effect on the layout as well, but if the SMPS section is considered separately, I was wondering what feedback people can give regarding the layout, and if there are any issues or improvements that could be made.

Comment: One comment is that you should add thermal relief to components on polygon pour. You or the assembler may have a hard time soldering components on polygon pour because it will act as a heat sink.

Comment: @efox29 Thanks for the suggestion - I'm guessing that really only applies to through hole/hand soldered components (there are a few on there that would benefit from thermal relief)

Comment: The thermal relief for SMD may also be required for future repairs/mods.

Comment: What is the via between U1 and C22 for? If it's leading to the power plane, that's not how I'd recommend doing it. You want the power (loosely used term here) to go from the plane to the capacitor to the chip. In other words, the cap should be between the source and the power pin of the chip. Otherwise it may not decouple the chip very well.

Comment: @derstrom8 That via is part of the trace that connects the HS pin of the LM5118 (pin 20) to the source of Q2.

Comment: @AmrBekhit I see. My point still stands, though--You should have the source and decoupling cap as close to the chip as possible, and make sure the cap is between the source and the chip. I haven't looked very hard, but I'm not seeing where your power source connects to the decoupling cap. It needs to be a direct connection.

Comment: @derstrom8 Sorry I misunderstood which via you meant! I know which one you mean now, just to the right of C22. Yes I see your point there, well spotted.