# LC filter inductor is making noise

Tags: filter, passive-networks, passive-filter

Inductor IN3 is making audible noise while I connect to 12V, 830mA supply from an AC/DC converter.

L1 is not present. It has been shorted.

U1 is an LM2576 from TI.

What might be the reason for this? How can I fix it?

[Datasheet of IN3](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/445/74437346220-1721807.pdf)

[image]

Comment: What is C2 exactly?  Is the output regulating within voltage and ripple specifications?  The [IL2576 datasheet](http://www.iksemi.com/pds/product/IL2576-xx-05%20(P).pdf) shows C2 as 1000µF to 2000µF.  But then again, that datasheet also confuses "mF" with "µF" so lends itself as suspect.

Comment: What does oscilloscope show on either side of IN3?

Answer (score 5):

For asynchronous buck-regulation circuits, if you don't have a fairly-high quiescent load on the output, the switching controller will move into a type of operation called burst-mode. In burst-mode, the controller chip will send small bursts of pulses separated by a fairly long time interval. It is the burst "pulse" and the time interval in between burst-pulses that drops into the audio range and, can have the effect you describe i.e. the inductor makes an audible noise.

[image]

Image from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77645/can-a-synchronous-regulator-chirp-in-burst-mode).

I would suggest that you determine what the minimum load current you might want and, apply a load resistor to emulate this current. Hopefully, it will force the LM2576 to operate in "normal" mode. Maybe experiment with a few loads to see at what point the problem disappears?

- [The meaning of burst mode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/285029/the-meaning-of-burst-mode)

From the [data sheet of the LM2576](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf?ts=1661412840778&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM2576%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dapp-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-eu%2526utm_content%253DLM2576%2526ds_k%253DLM2576%2BDatasheet%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DCjwKCAjwu5yYBhAjEiwAKXk_eEDwq_-b2xqLxZ_f2TIxZHf7XuBpiiTne8xqyGACx2FvUg_dYqYbDhoCCy8QAvD_BwE%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds) they specify a test circuit that has a load current of 0.5 amps: -

[image]

Comment: I have already provided loads such as ICs, LEDs and other related components. So that'll suffice?

Comment: No, maybe not. You should provide a load that takes a few tens or hundreds of milli-amps and see what happens. LEDs may barely take any current. See the data sheet addition I put in my answer. You should test it at 0.5 amps load and see what happens then, take the current lower to see at what point burst mode becomes a reality. If your normal operating current is below this I suggest you try using a synchronous buck converter.

Comment: I'm making use of the same circuit for many other applications having lesser current rating than this. But I never faced this issue. Issue is with IN1 not IN3

Comment: @Lex yes, I assumed you meant IN1 (although you said IN3 in your question). Are we done here or do you still have some queries?

Comment: Issue is that we were able to use this design in a totally different circuits having less current requirement but we didn't face this issue. So I don't think this the reason. Thanks for your insights @andy

Comment: I doubt this some issue with incoming 12V, when I switch to bench supply it was working fine.